# Use HttpClient within middleware pipeline?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, httpclient, middleware

I am working on an API project with ASP.NET Core and I have to consume a custom OAuth service (also an ASP.NET Core) the company owns. That service should be called on every request made to the API, to validate that the user is authorize to use that resource, so I thought I could create a Middleware on the API that would handle that request to the OAuth service.

My problem is that I am still learning C# and ASP.NET Core and, I am not sure if whether or not that could be accomplished. I did some Googling, but I couldn't find examples with HttpClient calls done on a Middleware. I wonder if someone could give me a hint on if whether or not I am going on the right road or, if that is considered bad practice, and that there are better ways of accomplish it.

Comment: This seems a little heavy-handed. Most oauth flows acknowledge that there is period of time for which it's acceptable to use a refreshable authorization token instead of hitting up the "request validation service" on every request. Is "reauthenticating" the user on *every* request really what you need?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick comment. I do notice it is a little heavy-handed, but they want to, at least for the moment, for that service to be used. I am suggesting the company to change into that workflow as well, but I was hoping I can work with what I have now, if possible.

Comment: You should be ok so long as you're careful to reuse a single HttpClient instance.

Comment: looks like an authentication scheme should do the job. don't think you need a middleware

Comment: `HttpClient` or `HttpContext` ?

Comment: HttpClient - my goal was to do an async http call to the custom Auth service from the Middleware, but by doing so I have to return a Task<Class> from the Invoke method of the middleware (that is expecting an HttpContext object to be returned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a custom authentication scheme and add it to your Authentications in `ConfigureServices`

Basically you need to implement `AuthenticationHandler` and inject `HttpClient`

```
public class CustomAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthOptions>
{


    public const string SchemeName = "CustomSchemeName";
    private readonly HttpClient _httpclient;

    public LocalAccessTokenValidationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<LocalAccessTokenValidationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock,  HttpClient httpclient)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _httpclient= httpclient;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // use _httpclient here and authenticate request and return AuthenticateResult
    }
```

And then add this to your authentication services

```
services.AddAuthentication(CustomAuthHandler.SchemeName) // setting CustomAuthHandler as the default
        .AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(CustomAuthHandler.SchemeName);
```

Register `HttpClient` as a Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton(new HttpClient());
```

Then you need to make sure all your controllers are marked as `[Authorize]`.

Check this [blog](https://ignas.me/tech/custom-authentication-asp-net-core-20/) for more details.
Check this [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for an idea on how to mark all controllers as authorized globally. This way you do not have to mark each controller with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: i don't get why `HttpClient` needs to be injected in a server-side application

Comment: It's best if you have one instance of `HttpClient` and use it everwhere. Microsoft also add new class called `HttpClientFactory` in ASP.NET Core 2.1. you can check it here, https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: since 2.1 is still in preview, I think as of now, making a singleton something like `services.AddSingleton(new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://google.com") });` should be safer

Comment: Of course, right now we should add a singleton service

Comment: @NevilleNazerane you edited my answer, did you mean `[Authorize]` instead of `[Authenticated]`?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: Well, not necessary a singleton. Basically you should have one `HttpClient` per endpoint. Using a single `HttpClient` for multiple endpoints can get hairy, as specifiying things like `BaseAddress` or default headers can then cause other requests to different endpoints in your application to fail. You really should use some sort of factory.

Comment: @ChrisPratt good point, thank you. I removed setting `BaseAddress`

Comment: @Kahbazi: Well that's *better*, but there's nothing stopping some piece of code from setting it later or, again, default headers. That then affects every other `HttpClient` use across the application, and could cause other requests you're making to suddenly fail for no obvious reason. If you don't want to go the full factory route, you can simply create one or more "accessor" classes that each create an instance of `HttpClient` and then scope those as singletons. Then, you can inject the appropriate "accessor" for each case. Not as elegant as a factory, but gets the job done.

Comment: @Kahbazi Thank you so much. This helps me a lot on understanding better an Authentication scheme on NETCore. I have  changed the middleware into this Attribute and things are working well, every request is making the call to the Auth service, althought I have to figure out on how to send some user data back to the controller once the Authorization have been accomplished. I would mark this answer as correct but, I am concerned that people may be comming here looking for the answer on how to make an HttpClient call within a Middleware. What do you guys suggest for this situation?

Comment: @FernandoJ.JiménezCalsín for passing info to controller, you should add user data as Claims in User Identity

Comment: @Kahbazi Excellent, thank you for the response. Would it be possible to override the [Authorize] attribute for the Authorization filters? Just wondering.

Comment: yes, you need to write your own class which inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: i really won't recommend extending the `AuthorizeAttribute`. Almost anything you would want to do can be done with schemes and policies

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Thank you for the suggestion. What I was trying to accomplish by extending the AuthorizeAttribute is to pass a Policy parameter from the Attribute to the AuthenticationHandler, because the controller is the one who knows which policy it needs to operate (in that way, the policy is not send within the Request). Although, I am still researching on how to pass that parameter from the controller to the AuthenticationHandler, if possible.